# Reportviewer Displays blank pages with no data

Tags: mysql, vb.net, rdlc

I have this program that executes the report viewer very well with the data from a table in mysql database. The problem is when I add two datepickers and a generate button to display the data between dates, the program displays a blank page with the column headers only. This is my code:

Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms

Public Class frmSalesReport
    Private Sub Closepb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Closepb.Click
        Me.Dispose()
    End Sub

```
Private Sub frmSalesReport_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Sub LoadReport()
    Dim rptDS As ReportDataSource
    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
    Try
        With ReportViewer1.LocalReport
            .ReportPath = Application.StartupPath & "\Reports\Report1.rdlc"
            .DataSources.Clear()
        End With

        Dim ds As New DataSet1
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter

        cn.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand("select invoice, subtotal, vat, discount, amountdue, sdate, user from tblpayment where sdate between '" & DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") & "' and '" & DateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") & "'", cn)
        da.Fill(ds.Tables("dtSales"))
        cn.Close()

        rptDS = New ReportDataSource("DataSet1", ds.Tables("dtSales"))
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rptDS)
        ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
        ReportViewer1.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent
        ReportViewer1.ZoomPercent = 100
    Catch ex As Exception
        cn.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message, vbCritical)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnGenerate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     btnGenerate.Click
    LoadReport()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I think a `ReportViewer` is a web control. I am not sure how well it would work in a WinForms application which is what this appears to be.

Comment: It is but Microsoft visual studio has it as a tool too. I actually figured out where my problem was. I had the wrong date format that weren't matching the format in my db.